# Using Node-Js as message passing layer

Tags: node.js, mpi, tcp

Is

```
  (client) node-js http request  <-----------> node-js http listen (server)
             ^                   100/1000 MBit/s     ^
             |                       LAN             |
             v                                       v
     a file in ramdrive                         a file in ramdrive 
            ^                                        ^
            |                                        |  
            v                                        v
        C# program requesting                     C# or Java program      
           compute on data                           computing
```

easier than

```
(client)C# tcp ip <--------------------------------->C#/Java tcp ip (server)
           socket      100/1000 Mbit/s LAN                         socket
```

in terms of error handling(such as half-open connections, acknowledgement packet management and picking right window/buffer size) and scalability (for 10-100 servers using tree-like connections)?

If node-js layer is to be used just for I/O, would it be better than MPI for a cluster on basic switches/routers(not infiniband for example)?

For now, **I'm trying tcp-ip option and already have too many exceptions to handle and far from finished**. There are max connections because of desktop os, the serialization of arrays also need checking against endianness of server and client and many more to counterpoise before sending/computing the data. Also everywhere it says async is best. I just started with a 1 thread for 1 connection version. Threaded version also has persistent local data to hold compute device information and compiled kernels(for opencl).

If I understand correctly, both mpi and node-js need their runtime be installed on servers and clients but tcp-ip doesn't need such thing. But this wouldn't balance other difficulties would it?

Adding ramdrive between node-js and C# came into my mind because it looks easy to access a file from node-js(and C#) with much less things to worry about than a tcp connection. Http listening is also nearly one-liner in node-js when it is just passing data.

Comment: Without knowing the details is hard to say, but the http solution will be slower than if you work a socket level. Zeromq is a very good solution for that kind of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of what you're doing, it's hard to recommend a specific solution... but I suspect you're re-inventing a solution.

Check out [Redis](http://redis.io/).  There are client libraries for most any language, it works over a network, handles all kinds of data types, and even supports pub/sub.  It's built to be ridiculously performant... the developers of Redis made a lot of the right trade-offs for many applications.